# Save a response body as file with FileSaver and blob

Tags: angular, blob

I want to download and save a file from an api. The name of my file is `text.txt` but the saved file is called: `_text.txt_` and the content of this file is: `[object Object]`

This is my function to download as file:

```
const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', this.oAuthService.getAccessToken()),
      params: new HttpParams().append('responseType', 'text'),
      observe: 'response' as 'response'
    }

    return this.http.get(this.fileServerUrl + 'file/download/' + filename + '/' + version, options)
      .subscribe(
        resp => { this.saveToFileSystem(resp)

      });
  }

  private saveToFileSystem(response) {
    const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Disposition');
    const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
    const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
    filename.replace(/"/g, '');
    console.log(filename);
    console.log(response.body)
    const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'text/plain' });
    saveAs(blob, filename);
  }
```

the output of the first console.log is text.txt and the console.log of the  response.body is: this is a test text..

so why is the saved file name with _ at the begin and end and the content not the text from the response body.

Thanks in advnace

Comment: you could enclose the problem you are facing in your question to be clearer as to what you seek help solving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(response.body)], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

And for `_text.txt_`:
String is immutable type. So filename.replace... will not change filename value, it's returns new value.
You have to create new variable:

```
const newFileName = filename.replace(/"/g, '');
...
saveAs(blob, newFileName);
```

or just put `filename.replace(/"/g, '')` into `saveAs`

```
saveAs(blob, filename.replace(/"/g, ''));
```