# Angular 7 - using FileSaver.js to download an Excel file not working

Tags: excel, angular, filesaver.js

I am sending a post request to my back end to receive an Excel file. I can see in postman that my backend is sending the Excel, but in Angular, I cannot download it using the `FileSaver.Js` library. Any ideas?

Here is my html markup:

```
<button (click)="excel()">Export Excel</button>
```

Here is my service class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private data: DataService , private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

    ngOnInit()  {
    }

    excel() {
        this.data.excel().toPromise()
            .then(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response));
    }

    private saveToFileSystem(response) {
        const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
        const filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
        const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'text/plain' });

        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
    }
}
```

And here is my data class method for requesting to backend:

```
excel() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    console.log("sentin")
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/Excel', { headers: headers })
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52078363/4696516 this answer. You may need to stringify your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally the answer:

I should have made these changes:

1. Change the method `saveFileSystem` to:

   ```
   private saveToFileSystem(response) {
       const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(response.body)], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8' });
       FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
   }
   ```
2. Add a response type to my `HttpPost` like this:

   ```
   { responseType: 'text' }
   ```